# Using XMLTeX to typeset OpenDocument Text

Tags: xml, open-office

I know that XMLTeX has already been used to typeset TEI documents, but has anyone publicly worked on a set of environment files and stylesheets to typeset OpenDocument Text? I have been looking for such things lately, but I could not find anything.

The rationale is that I want a comprehensive solution for typesetting ODT documents produced by OpenOffice and LibreOffice without having to rely on XSLT. Writer2LateX does a great job in some situations, but for more consistency and efficiency I deem it eminently desirable to be able to define the style of an ODT document directly in TeX and then apply this style to a set of documents that have the same structure and use the same styles.

Writer2LaTeX uses Java, XSLT and components from the OpenOffice SDK to produce a relatively faithful LaTeX document from the provided ODT; this means that every time the source ODT is modified, a new LaTeX document must be produced from it, with *all* content and *all* styles converted each time. What is more, Writer2LaTeX must more or less “reinvent the wheel” each time it is given a new paragraph, character or list style, resulting in environment and command definitions which are extremely verbose. It would be great to instead create concise and generic environment definitions for each ODT element and then create more detailed definitions for each style attribute.

Am I making sense? I am aware of the fact that what I am asking for is huge. After all, to get the expected results, one would have to provide definitions for *all* the elements of *all* the relevant XML namespaces (a typical ODT file has many besides the standard ODF 1.2 namespaces). However, if someone provided those generic element definitions “once and for all”, then the person who is in charge of typesetting a given document could concentrate on defining environments for the particular styles encountered in the particular document.

Comment: ooh xmltex:-) If I was doing this I'd use XSLT, it really is a _lot_ easier to get XSLT to handle the XML re-arrangement and write out some tex rather than get TeX to do it at the same time.

Comment: Oh, now that is an interesting comment, considering the person who makes it :-). So would it arguably be better to improve writer2LaTeX’s XSLT instead?

Comment: I haven't looked at their XSLT, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: I’ll give it a go; I had already planned to contact the main developer about his XSLT filters for XHTML: these are also invaluable resources that need more love.

Comment: Seriously: Forget about XMLTeX and use ConTeXt instead. Or use pandoc.

Comment: I would really appreciate some tips on using ConTeXt with OpenDocument Text :-). I do use Pandoc extensively, however when I need to produce OpenDocument Text from Markdown or another light markup language I use Org-mode, as I find it easier to extend and customize (Org allows you to include “raw” ODT and, among other things, character styles and text sections). When I need to start *from* ODT and typeset with TeX, however, unfortunately neither Pandoc nor Org can help me (except if I export ODT to HTML, but in many cases this is undesirable).

Comment: I edited my question to add details about Writer2LaTeX: actually, it uses XSLT only for MathML, the rest is handled by Java code and components from the OpenOffice SDK. Eventually, I might answer this question myself, as I am working on some fresh XSLT. Repository coming eventually, will link to it from here.

Comment: See ConTeXt wiki article on typesetting [TEI](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TEI_xml) to get an idea of how to typeset xml using context

Comment: This is indeed a good starting point and I see how I could do the same with ODT. The [My Way article about XHTML](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/tas/xhtml.pdf) is invaluable too.

Comment: I'd be interested in the reason for not "wanting to rely on" XSLT2, because this would be the obvious and reliable solution.

Comment: I have learned much since the time when I initially asked this question, and now I understand the benefits of the modern XQuery and XPath data model. I am getting to grips with XQuery 3.0 and XSLT 2.0. I am also looking forward to XSLT 3.0; if I understand well, this new version already has implementations. Back in 2013, the reason why I said I didn’t want to rely on XSLT 2.0 was that it is not implemented natively in browsers, in LibreOffice, etc. Now it is one of my greatest wishes to see those new standards implemented widely.

Comment: I like the fact that I can use both XSLT and XQuery as transformation languages, but I still wonder about serialization: TeXML (Python), xml2tex (Scheme), XSLT’s serialization... There are many options, and I have yet to decide on the correct level of abstraction on the XML side and on the TeX side. It seems to depend on the genre of the texts and on the depth of their markup structure.

Comment: Author of the two documents on ConTeXt here. I often go this route: LibreOffice document – xml representation – pdf typeset with ConTeXt. However, all my attempts to use the odf file directly have been unsuccessful; I've found the xml unpredictable and inconsistent across documents. So I usually export the document to xhtml, do a little clean up and then typeset this simpler xml document. May not be what you want to hear, but IMHO, a complete definition of the entire odf xml is not just huge, it's unrealistic.

Comment: Exactly! I agree now. I’m glad to see my open question still generating interest and, indeed, now that I have learned more about programming I no longer wish for a monolithic one-stop solution for ODF export. It is true that LibreOffice’s ODF code is quite unpredictable, especially with regards to the elements that correspond to the HTML *phrasing* content category. Converting to cleaner (X)HTML has also been a favored route of mine for some time. Another development that has helped tremendously is the maturation of Firefox’s Developer Tools, which help me inspect ODF XML before conversion.

Comment: As of 2017 I did some routine convertions of OpenOffice ODT to markdown via pandoc to LaTeX via pandoc again. My goal was editing the markdown anyway, but it worked quite effortlessly. So, pandoc seems to have matured a lot these years.

Comment: When you want to  go the route from LaTeX to OpenDocument, you can try tex4ht. It can create odt directly from tex files. And it uses LaTeX for that purpose.